# How do I achieve reverse mapping in TS with enum

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

so I have an enum with string indexing

```
enum MyEnum {
  str = "string"
}

console.log(MyEnum['str']); // string
console.log(MyEnum['string']); // undefined
```

I want to be able to get the key via the value i.e.

```
console.log(MyEnum['string']); // str
```

However it gives me `undefined`. Is there a way to achieve that?

Here is my attempt

```
export enum EventType {
  JOB = "job"
}

type EventTypeKey = keyof typeof EventType;

const EVENT_TYPE_KEYS = new Map<EventType, EventTypeKey>(
  Object.entries(EventType).map(([key, value]: [EventTypeKey, EventType]) => [
    value,
    key
  ])
);
```

However TS compiler gave me a bunch of cryptic compile errors

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that achieves what you are looking for:

```
enum MyEnum {
  str = "string"
}

console.log(MyEnum['str']); // string
console.log((Object.keys(MyEnum)).find(key => (MyEnum as any)[key] == 'string')); // str
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the advice. do you know why my attempt doesn't pass the compiler?

Answer (score 0):

@basarat used `Object.keys` because argument type of `Object.keys` is object, which enum confirms to.

So you can use Object.keys on enum.

But argument type of `Object.entries` is strictly key value pair, which enum does not confirm to.

So you can't use Object.entries on enum.

[Read more about enum on typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)

By op's request, here's his solution without type error

```
const EVENT_TYPE_KEYS = new Map<EventType, EventTypeKey>(
    Object.keys(EventType).map((key: EventTypeKey) => [
        EventType[key],
        key
    ])
)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for pointing that out! is it possible to tweak my solution a little bit or rewrite the solution to pass the compiler?

Comment: hey thanks for the update. However I still see a compiler error after pasting your solution in. It says types of paramaters 'key' and 'value' are incompatible. Can you check again? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of
(1)EventTypeKey type and
(2)Type for `new Map<EventTypeKey, EventTypeValue>` and `.map` method need to have same type.

Try the following

```
enum EventType {
  JOB = "job"
}

type EventTypeKey = string;
type EventTypeValue =  string;

const EVENT_TYPE_KEYS = new Map<EventTypeKey, EventTypeValue>(
  Object.entries(EventType).map(([key, value]: [EventTypeKey, EventTypeValue]) => [
    value,
    key
  ])
);

console.log(EVENT_TYPE_KEYS.get("job"));
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply... Is there a way to make `EventTypeKey` and `EventTypeValue` more specificaly typed?